# SAS gplot procedure always puts data on the same axis

Tags: plot, graphics, sas

So I have this problem:
I want to very simple plot on x axis put time and on y axis put calculation. But the graphs are always the same.

- SAS 9.2.
- sas gplot procedure. Plot statement.

SAS documentation says:

> **y-variable*x-variable<=n>
>
>   plots the values of two variables and can assign a SYMBOL definition to the plot.**

But that does not work in given example below.
First generate some data:

```
data graphData;
    format 
        line $256.
        checkDate yymmddn8. checkTime time.;
    input line $256.;

    dtTime = scan(line,1," ");
    checkDate = input(substr(dtTime,1.8),yymmdd8.);
    checkTime = input(
                catx(":",
                    substr(dtTime,9,2),
                    substr(dtTime,11,2),
                    "00")
                ,time8.);
    load_average_1 = scan(scan(line,-3,","),2,":");
datalines;
201703200800   8:00am  up 56 day(s),  9:36,  0 users,  load average: 0.05, 0.05, 0.05
201703200900   9:00am  up 56 day(s), 10:36,  0 users,  load average: 2.18, 2.27, 2.25
201703201000  10:00am  up 56 day(s), 11:36,  0 users,  load average: 3.92, 4.42, 4.94
201703201100  11:00am  up 56 day(s), 12:36,  0 users,  load average: 1.85, 2.68, 4.19
201703201200  12:00pm  up 56 day(s), 13:36,  1 user,  load average: 2.64, 3.00, 3.09
201703201300   1:00pm  up 56 day(s), 14:36,  1 user,  load average: 3.84, 3.89, 3.65
201703201400   2:00pm  up 56 day(s), 15:36,  1 user,  load average: 1.74, 2.14, 2.32
201703201500   3:00pm  up 56 day(s), 16:36,  1 user,  load average: 1.29, 2.09, 2.96
201703201600   4:00pm  up 56 day(s), 17:36,  0 users,  load average: 3.46, 4.99, 5.29
201703201700   5:00pm  up 56 day(s), 18:36,  0 users,  load average: 3.79, 3.30, 3.74
201703201800   6:00pm  up 56 day(s), 19:36,  0 users,  load average: 2.04, 2.17, 2.45
201703201900   7:00pm  up 56 day(s), 20:36,  0 users,  load average: 2.29, 1.86, 1.57
;
run;
```

Now the graphs. In plot statement I put checkTime and load_average_1 combinations.

```
symbol1 color=vibg interpol=join value=dot;

PROC GPLOT DATA=graphdata;
     PLOT checkTime*load_average_1;
     by checkDate;
RUN;

PROC GPLOT DATA=graphdata;
     PLOT load_average_1*checkTime;
     by checkDate;
RUN;
```

Generated plots:
As You can see the plots are the same

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update

So it was problem is with graphical option device (*goption device*).
When DEVICE=ACTIVEX the axis does not switch.
When device is changed to png (Statement: *goptions device=png;*) graphs are drawn correctly.

Answer (score 0):

When I run the code in 9.3, the graphs are NOT the same; the axes differ.  I would try your code again, maybe add a `quit;` statement after each `run;` (shouldn't change anything, but can't hurt.)  Maybe try running in batch also.  Finally, I would add a different title to each graph, just to make sure you aren't looking at the same graph twice.   If you're in DM SAS, the graph viewer does not advance automatically.

```
title1 "Graph 1: checkTime*load_average_1" ;
PROC GPLOT DATA=graphdata;
 PLOT checkTime*load_average_1;
 by checkDate;
RUN;quit;
title1;

title1 "Graph 2: load_average_1*checkTime" ;    
PROC GPLOT DATA=graphdata;
     PLOT load_average_1*checkTime;
     by checkDate;
RUN;quit;
title1;
```